# How to pass boolean value from the API response to child component

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to pass boolean from API Java response object to child component. What can I change to use isFavourite value in the child component? The main question is how to pass boolean values to other components. Currently, I receive an undefined value on *isFavourite*.

**RESPONSE**

```
  {"id":12,"title":"The Lord Of The Rings","isUserFavourite":true}
```

**Movie**

```
    const Movie = ({match}) => {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

    useEffect(
        () =>
            fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/movie/fetch/${match.params.id}`, {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    setMovie(data);
                }),
        []
    );

    return (
      <div>
            <h2>{ad.title}</h2>
            <FavouriteButton id={movie.id} isUserFavourite={movie.isUserFavourite}/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Ad;
```

**Favourite button**

```
    const FavouriteButton = (props) => {
    const [isFavourite, setIsFavourite] = useState(props.isUserFavourite);


    const onClickHandler = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "PATCH",
        };
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/user/favourite/${props.id}`, requestOptions).then(
            setIsFavourite(prevState => !prevState));
        ;
    }
    return <div>{isFavourite ? (<p>FAVOURITE</p>) : (<p>NOT-FAVOURITE</p>)}
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>FAVOURITE/NOT-FAVOURITE</button>
    </div>
}

export default FavouriteButton;
```

Comment: Booleans can be passed as a prop just like any other data type.  The way you're trying to access it (`props.isUserFavourite`) is fine.  The best place to start is making sure that `movie.isUserFavourite` actually is a boolean, like you expect, and that it isn't actually undefined

Comment: It's my API, in the response object there is a boolean, 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the component before the API is finished hence the state inside the child component is being initialized as 'undefined' before the API call is done, try to add a loader or a condition to check if the API is not finished yet don't render the component FavouriteButton

Comment: Thank you, it worked.